# Trailhead - Modify Layout in Lightning

Tags: lightning, trailhead

I am attempting this Trailhead exercise wherein I have to remove unwanted fields from the layout.

This is my first foray into lightning as such I am at a loss as to how to achieve this.

[image]

The fields circled in yellow needs to be removed from the layout (this case layout is shown upon clicking New in Case Related List from Fulfillment Layout)

[image]

Can someone tell me where I should be looking into to edit this particular case layout (New Case layout from Fulfillment) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Go to the object manager from setup and choose case.

2) Click on **"case page layout"** and from the **"Page Layout Assignment"** button identify the Page layout assigned to the profile and update the case page layout.

**Web Email** is **always required on the layout**, you may not be able to remove the field.
Ref: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212544&type=1